# How do I format a text box in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo

I want to import a table (created and formatted in MS word?) to appear as text in the MapInfo layout window.  Obviously this isn't individual data records which appear in the MapInfo browser window.  So would I need to format the MS Word table, save the file as a JPG/png format then import into MapInfo as a raster file?  Is there another way in MapInfo of doing this - just type the table contents as text into the layout window then draw a rectangle around the text and make this box transparent but with a border?

Answer (score 1):

Both of the methods you mention are possible but only really suited to data that remains static; although they will give you a lot more control over the styling of the table.

If your data is likely to change, you could save the table as an Excel spreadsheet and then import this into Mapinfo.
Open a browser window and adjust the size and style and then add to your layout window as you would add a map/legend etc.

This will allow you to easily update the data and layout within Mapinfo without any hassle (or if you use a linked XLS or MDB, then the data will automatically refresh when you next load it).